# MySQL error 1064 on create table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to create table with

```
CREATE TABLE `notes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt`  TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

But I get a **1064 error** and I can't see what is wrong

Comment: Please include the *full text* of any errors. They're usually very specific.

Comment: You should also steer towards using `utf8` or `utf8mb4` in any new tables you create. It's also a good idea to use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default "string" type column. There's no reason to clamp these to a rather arbitrary 45 characters. I'd also recommend using `DATETIME` columns in preference to `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: See the error text. MySQL lets you know the location of error with line number. It also gives suggestions to resolve the error.